# What is the most stretchable rubber thread?

Tags: materials

I'm looking for a rubber thread that can be stretched elastically to 10 or 20 times of its original length. Does such material exist? Which is the best one in this respect?

Comment: Please see [the Engineering.SE position on recommendation/finding stuff questions.](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/10/368)

Comment: Off-topic? Then where not? I moved here from physics.stackexchage because I was advised to do this there.

Comment: If so, I'm afraid you were misled.

Comment: @Air Then, where is the good place to ask such a question, in your opinion? Who knows the mechanical properties of materials beyond physicists and engineers?

Comment: There are a great number of message boards and discussion forums for scientists and engineers online. We are not a message board or discussion forum. We do have [chat], which has no explicit restriction on topic or breadth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick lmgtfy reveals a [hydroelastomer](http://www.livescience.com/22945-super-stretchy-material-also-super-strong.html) made of alginate polyacrylamide and water with a stretch ratio over 20:1.  I believe that article refers to [this paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3642868/) .

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a broad question, but in an engineering context the main properties you are looking for are [elastic modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_modulus) which is stress/strain is how much a material stretched under load and [ultimate tensile strength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_tensile_strength) OR [yield strength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yield_(engineering)) which are both measures of how much load a material will sustain before it fails.

Materials with a high modulus of elasticity are broadly classified as 'rubbers', this may include 'natural' rubbers (derived from latex) or various silicone, vinyls,  polyurethanes etc etc. This category of materials is usually referred to in materials science as *elastomer*s, although the term *rubber* is also widely used